# Unable to compare/return nil object in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am not new to Objective-C but I am new to swift. I used to compare object if they were nil in Objective-C but I am unable to do that in swift.

```
func getCurrentUser() -> Users{

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
    var fetchedUsers = NSArray()
    do {
        let fetchedEntities = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as NSArray
        fetchedUsers = fetchedEntities
    } catch {
        // Do something in response to error condition
    }

    var userToSend = Users()

    for user in fetchedUsers{

        let currentUser = user as! Users
        if(currentUser.isSignedIn == 1)
        {
            userToSend = currentUser
            break
        }
    }
    return userToSend
}
```

If my userToSend is nil, I am unable to check it where the method is called, code crashes.

This is where my code crashes:

```
    let currentUser = UserDBService().getCurrentUser()

    let userID = String(currentUser.userId)
```

How I can do that?

**UPDATE**

I have used Michael's answer but still I get crash:

[image]

Have used Eendje's solution and I get this:

[image]

Comment: What debug information do you get when it crashes?

Comment: Another question: why do you fetch every user and then check the `isSignedIn` property?  Why not just fetch entities with that property set to begin with?  It seems that you are new to core data, and not just Swift.

Comment: If there are no fetched users, or none are signed in, your `getCurrentUser` will return a newly created `Users` instance. I'm guessing that it's `userId` property is nil and is force-unwrapped which is causing a crash. Objects in Swift cannot contain nil - only Optionals can contain nil, and they are declared with a suffix of "?" or "!".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func getCurrentUser() -> Users? {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
    let fetchedUsers = (try? managedobjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)) as? [Users] ?? []

    // If there are no instances of Users with isSignedIn == 1, it returns nil
    guard let index = fetchedUsers.indexOf({ $0.isSignedIn == 1 }) else { return nil }

    // Since it passed the guard, it can return the user
    return fetchedUsers[index]
}

// Returns an optional String
let userID = String(getCurrentUser()?.userID)
```

Rewrote your function a bit, this should be able to work.

Comment: What kind of error? Did you change the return type to `Users?`?

Comment: In else, i have to return nil so i can compare if fetch request has returned a user or nothing.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. In my answer, it should return `nil` when there is are no `Users` found with `isSignedIn == 1`. It doesn't check whether fetch request has returned anything since that's not needed anymore.

Comment: Is there a reason you removed this answer as answered and marked the duplication instead?

Comment: that was a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on my comment, it looks like `getCurrentUser` should return an Optional:

```
func getCurrentUser() -> Users? {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
    var fetchedUsers = NSArray()
    do {
        let fetchedEntities = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as NSArray
        fetchedUsers = fetchedEntities
    } catch {
        // Do something in response to error condition
    }

    for user in fetchedUsers {
        if let currentUser = user as? Users {
            if(currentUser.isSignedIn == 1) {
                return currentUser
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Then you would call it as:

```
if let currentUser = UserDBService().getCurrentUser() {
    let userID = String(currentUser.userId)
} else {
    // no current user
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this crash either way

```
if let currentUser = UserDBService().getCurrentUser() {
    let userID = String(currentUser.userId)
} else {

}
```

OR

```
 let currentUser = UserDBService().getCurrentUser()
     if(currentUser!=nil){
        let userID = String(currentUser.userId)
     }else{
        // Nil handling code
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    func getCurrentUser() -> Users? {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
        let fetchedUsers = (try? managedobjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)) as? [Users] ?? []

     returns nil
        guard let index = fetchedUsers.indexOf({ $0.isSignedIn == 1 }) 
        else 
        { 
            return nil 
        }

        return fetchedUsers[index]
    }

//Call your method like this
let userID = String(getCurrentUser(context)?.userID)
```

Remove the `context` if you are using shared context or you are having a `self.context` then use `self.context` here.

Comment: Am I seeing double, or is this exactly the same as my answer except having a faulty line (`returns nil`) extra? Why is this answer even upvoted and marked as answered?